# Guess my laptop doesnt use my nvidia gpu

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, nvidia, gpu

Well, my pc's hardware is not bad. But it had a lot of damage in the past and its 7 years old. When it started to crash on windows and literally had times frozen more than normal, i thinked its time to use linux. Ubuntu first, than pearOS, than elementaryOS, and than Pardus. It was better at all of them, but not as i expected. Then i realized that damages are not the only problem. So i started looking answers for this questions after me trying installing Nvidia Drivers with .run installer:

---

- How could i know if my gpu is being used as default?
- If it isn't being used as default, how can i set it as default?
- How can i use this gpu only in a program (like playing a game with gpu, when cpu operates every other thing) when i want?

---

And there is some info:

My Laptop Model => Lenovo Yoga 500-80r5

**lspci** output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**lspci | grep VGA** output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
```

**nvidia-smi** output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.60.02    Driver Version: 510.60.02    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      3MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       947      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: lmk if i should add some more outputs.

Comment: good news: `lspci | grep VGA` hides your nvidia card; it's there in the output of `lspci` as `3D controller: NVIDIA…`.

Answer (score 0):

> How could i know if my gpu is being used as default?

Look at `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`.

> If it isn't being used as default, how can i set it as default?

Install the correct combination of drivers, and/or write an `xorg.conf`.

> How can i use this gpu only in a program (like playing a game with gpu, when cpu operates every other thing) when i want?

Extremely difficult.

Comment: well i checked logs and i guess its using cpu as gpu (intel). and i ran command nvidia-xconfig then rebooted. it didnt opened. i deleted xorg.config with live system. So what to do to write a proper xorg.conf